# Migration of kibana dashboards

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I exported all the visualizations and dashboards from dev and imported into prod.

Even I have created all the index patterns and all the required indices into prod equivalent to dev, still, my reports are not working.

when I open the dashboard, it showed me the error that, index not found.

Would anyone tell what I need to do to fix whiling doing the migration of reports?

Comment: For each index in `elasticsearch` for which you have any `visualization`/`dashboard`, you need to have a respective `index pattern` in `kibana` . So even if you have all the `elasticsearch` `indices` in the place you will still have to create the respective `kibana` `index patterns`.

Comment: Yes, @RajRajeshwarSinghRathore I totally understand, I know without index pattern no visualization will work.

Comment: But consider the case that in dev if I made the same visualization with one index pattern and once after import into prod if I change the name of the pattern, means now the pattern is not the same as dev, will my visualization work or if not then what to do in this case.

Comment: I hope my answer clarifies and resolves this case.

Comment: Did the below answer worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I open the dashboard, it showed me the error that, index not found.

This will be resolved once you have the same `index` in the `prod` as you have in the `dev`.

> But consider the case that in dev if I made the same visualization with one index pattern and once after import into prod if I change the name of the pattern, means now the pattern is not the same as dev, will my visualization work or if not then what to do in this case.

For this, there is a way to resolve it in `kibana`. When you try to import a `dev` visualization in `prod` and a matching `index pattern` is not found then you will get an `Index Pattern Conflicts` pop up where you can map the visualization you are importing with any of the similar available index present in `prod` like below:

[image: Index Pattern Conflicts Resolution]

Hope this resolves your issue.